# Exceptions in Old Java Code

Tags: java

I am working with old code in Java from back when there were no generics. The hashMap is defined in that code without generics like:

```
Map A = new HashMap();
```

In this code how I would like to identify what to put in the key and value, and if user can put any key than how would it compare it. Since equals method is not overwritten?

Comment: Reference values. *Shudder*.

Comment: There is no problem. But if you need to maintain a large legacy system, start with adding generics. Update APIs using deprecated marks. Use FindBugs. Because any Exception must be due to some error.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately since there is no generics defined for the map you can't constraint on what can be put. For comparison the equals method will be called and if its not overridden for the key that you put then Object.equals will be called

Comment: In this case the code is totally dependable on the type of key we are inserting and it might create exception if there is different types of keys is inserted(due to user input)

Answer (score 1):

Even with generics, a user can put any key/value pair inside a map they want. The following code compiles just fine and will work perfectly at runtime:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>(  );
(Map)map).put( "key", new Double(2) );
```

It will only be a problem when I have code like

```
(String)map.get( "key" );
```

as this will cause a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

- If you are creating an API and you expose a mutable `Map` with generics, you can assume that a user will only put in values of the correct type
- If you are creating an API and you expose a mutable `Map` without generics, you need to document it clearly. In such case, you could consider not exposing the map, but instead provide a `put` method on the API instead where you hardcode the type of objects you accept
- If you are simply writing your own internal code and are stuck with JDK1.4 or lower, you have full control over what goes in that map. Just be careful. Same applies if you work against a legacy API. It will/should be documented what can be put in the map, and you need to respect that.

Answer (score 0):

In the days before generics, all containers worked with Object objects.

It is the duty of the programmer to make sure everything he puts into the container is of compatible types.

In this case it shouldn't be too problematic if there are different classes of objects used as keys, because `HashMap` relies on the `hashCode` and `equals` methods, and those don't throw exceptions if they are properly written.

In case the `equals` method is not overridden, it probably uses Object's `equals` which basically compares references. But it should be noted that classes like Integer and Date do have their own `equals` methods. They will not be true for anything which is not of the same class, though.

The real issue with such collections is that when you retrieve anything from them, you have to make absolutely sure that you got the correct type.

So in the old days, there used to be a lot of `if (o instanceof MyClass) then...` where collections were involved and the programmer had no control of the types of the objects.

This is why generics were invented.